# How to exclude a particular project from Continuous Integration

Tags: .net-4.0, continuous-integration, projects-and-solutions, windows-server-2008-r2, build-server

I use TFS2010 for source control and a build agent on windows server 2008 R2 (x64) for continuous integration.

Recently, we introduced a lightweight client application X that uses Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies to interact with Excel. The app has many dependencies to various projects in the solution. No other project have any dependency to X.

This is all well and good except that X wont build on the build server. From reading a few blog posts and some posts here on StackOverflow, I understand that it is not advisable to attempt to install these PIA's on my x64 build server. And that doing so will involve a bit of hacking in registry.

The solution has more than 30 projects and I do not want to duplicate the .sln in order to create a bastard BuildServerVersion.sln (or something) that contains the 29 projects that I DO want to build on the build server.

Is there a simple way to either satisfy the dependencies to the Office 2007 PIAs or to make the build agent stop trying to build that particular project? I suppose we could build and deploy just app X from a developer machine. It is an internal tool, anyway.